# Carrot Search > 3 levels

Tags: javascript, carrot

I am using [carrotsearch](https://get.carrotsearch.com/circles) circles and also [foamtree](https://get.carrotsearch.com/foamtree), the free versions as it doesn't matter to my client if the logos are on the graph.  FoamTree is simple to set how many levels deep you want to visualize, in my case 5 (0-4). I can not seem to find that with Circles. Am i supposed to provide my own drill down from 3-5?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I don't find any relevant mentions in the [api docs](https://get.carrotsearch.com/circles/demo/api/index.html)

EDIT: I saw the response from @Stanislaw Osinski, and indeed i was running down an incorrect path, the issue i seem to have is that, the nodes with > 3 levels are not being drawn at all.  In FoamTree those levels are visible, but here nothing, even from the first level...back to the drawing board.

EDIT 1:  The levels are indeed there, but there was something wrong with expansion, and it would only concentrate on groups with similar weights to display and not expand to the versions that have higher numbers and move levels.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FoamTree has a setting to limit the visible hierarchy depth due to performance reasons. For Circles, the maximum depth is not so much of a concern, so it will display all the hierarchy levels you provide in the `dataObject`. To limit the number of levels, you can prune the data object you provide to Circles to remove the levels you don't want to display.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer(by me) is correct, I found I was actually looking to  adjust the property `visibleGroupCount` accordingly from the desired starting point.